# Converting str to int in Python

Tags: python, type-conversion

I am currently trying to learn Python from a book and I am running into a problem. Basically I am supposed to write a program to do something called the Collatz sequence. The code is as follows:

```
print("Please enter a number")
number = input()

int(number)

while number > 1:
        collatz()

def collatz(number):
        if number % 2 == 0:
                number = number // 2
                print(number)
                return number
        else:
                number = 3 * number + 1
                print(number)
                return number
```

So when I try to execute the code above, I get the following output:

> RESTART: C:/Users/Gillian/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python35-32/Collatz.py 
>   Please enter a number
>   12
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:/Users/Gillian/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python35-32/Collatz.py", line 6, in 
>       while number > 1: 
>   TypeError: unorderable types: str() > int()
>   Blockquote

Obviously, my variable is being read as a string when it should be an integer. My question is - why? I thought that the part on line 4 where I change the datatype of number to int should fix that but it did not.

The instructions for what I'm trying to accomplish, if that matters to my question, are [here](https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter3/) at the bottom of the page.

Comment: You are not assigning the result of `int(number)` to anything.  Consider `number = int(number)`.

Answer (score 1):

After doing `int(number)`, you have to assign it to `number` again:

```
number = int(number)
```

This is because `int(number)` by itself doesn't change `number`, it simply returns a version of it cast to integer type.

You can also simplify your code by combining input and casting into one:

```
number = int(raw_input("Please enter a number"))
```

in Python 2.7. In Python 3, replace `raw_input` with `input`.

Comment: ahh you beat me by seconds :P tell him about combining his prompt and ill delete mine :P

Comment: Deal, and done. :)

Comment: @GillianWeisgram Better to ask forgiveness than permission. :) But yes, fire away.